# How to download specific GIF images (condition: phd*.gif) from a website using Python's BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup

I have the following code that downloads *all* images from a web-link.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urlparse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlretrieve
import os 
import sys

def main(url, out_folder="/test/"):
"""Downloads all the images at 'url' to /test/"""
soup = bs(urlopen(url))
parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

for image in soup.findAll("img"):
    print "Image: %(src)s" % image
        filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
        parsed[2] = image["src"]
        outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
        if image["src"].lower().startswith("http"):
            urlretrieve(image["src"], outpath)
        else:
            urlretrieve(urlparse.urlunparse(parsed), outpath)

    def _usage():
    print "usage: python dumpimages.py http://example.com [outpath]"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = sys.argv[-1]
    out_folder = "/test/"
    if not url.lower().startswith("http"):
        out_folder = sys.argv[-1]
        url = sys.argv[-2]
        if not url.lower().startswith("http"):
            _usage()
            sys.exit(-1) 
    main(url, out_folder)
```

I want to modify it so that it downloads only images named as 'phd210223.gif' (for example), that is, images satisfying the condition: 'phd*.gif'

And I want to put it in a loop, so that after fetching such images from one webpage, it increments the page ID by 1 and downloads the same from the next page: 'http://www.example.com/phd.php?id=2'

How can I do this?

Comment: There are really two questions here: better split it into two SO questions: first one - this one about checking for image name, second for scaling this to multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the name in the loop, you can use `BeautifulSoup`'s [built-in support for regular expressions](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression). Provide the compiled regular expression as a value of `src` argument:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs # note, you should use beautifulsoup4

for image in soup.find_all("img", src=re.compile('phd\d+\.gif$')):
    ...
```

`phd\d+\.gif$` regular expression would search for text starting with `phd`, followed by 1 or more digits, followed by dot, followed by `gif` at the end of the string.

Note that you are using an outdated and unmaintained `BeautifulSoup3`, switch to `beautifulsoup4`:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Thanks, now my code downloads just the GIF I want. Any ideas how I can automate the loop to go through different pages on the site? (...php?id=2, ...php?id=3...)

Comment: @intellikid well, as I commented to the question - I think you should elaborate it into a separate question. This one is about checking the image links. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @intellikid check the value of `soup` variable and make sure you see the images there.

Comment: I just wrote a two line Bash script that kept on invoking the python script in a loop for different webpage ID's. That was easier than modifying the python code itself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression can help to solve this! when pattern is found in string/url, a match object would be returned, otherwise None.

```
import re
reg = re.compile('phd.*\.gif$')
str1 = 'path/phd12342343.gif'
str2 = 'path/dhp12424353153.gif'
print re.search(reg,str1)
print re.search(reg,str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using python default tools so I use html.parser, what you need it something like this:

```
import re, urllib.request, html.parser
class LinksHTMLParser(parse.HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, length):
            super().__init__()
            self.gifs = list()

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
            if tag == "a":
                    for name, value in attrs:
                            if name == "href":
                                gifName = re.split("/", value)[-1]
                                if *gifNameCondition*:
                                    self.gifs.append(value)

    parser = LinksHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(urllib.request.urlopen("YOUR URL HERE").read().decode("utf-8"))
    for gif in parser.gifs:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(*local path to download gif to*, gif)
```